# AJAX JSON + PHP JSON error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've got a jQuery AJAX code, which recieves JSON-type data from php file. Wihout dataType: "json" everything is ok. But I need JSON-type data. Text recieved is a valid JSON code

> **{"ok":"false","answer":"All fields must be filled"}**

But when I user dataType, I've got an error

> **Object "parsererror" SyntaxError**

Here's JS code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : "testing/regtest.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data : {
            mail : $('#mail_field').val(),
            username : $('#username_field').val(),
            password : $('#password_field').val(),
            password_2 : $('#rep_password_field').val()
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data.ok);
        },
        error: function(a,b,c) { console.log(a,b,c); }
    });
```

Thanks for any help!

Update:
Here's php server-side code:
http://jsfiddle.net/VfQbz/1/

Update 2: It works in IE9 but doesn't work in chrome

Comment: Is the server-side script working properly? The JS itself looks fine.

Comment: Yep. Everything is ok with serverside

Comment: Where exacly does that error occur? Server or client-side?

Comment: Is the retrieved JSON valid? Already tried http://jsonlint.com/ ? Looks like a parsing problem to me

Comment: Client-side. And it occurs only with dataType set to jQuery. Retrieved JSON is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this works, but IMHO the problem is PHP's lousy JSON encoding function. Try:

```php
if (check_post() === true) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password_2'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    if (valid_data($password, $password2, $username, $mail) === true){
        $answer = json_encode(array("ok" => "true", "answer" =>     $service_messages["account_registered"]));
        echo "'".$answer."'"; // Note the additional single quotes
    }
}
```

By digging into the jQuery source I found the error to occur in the response parsing. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Does your PHP code sets the correct header?

`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` tells jquery to treat the returned string as json data, regardless of what the http headers say.

Comment: Well, I have this code `$.getJSON(url, core.ProcessJsonResponse).error(core.ShowError);` and this does not work without the `Kohana::$content_type = 'application/json';` syntax. Only with content-type set I do not see HTML tab at firebug HTTP request result.

Comment: What does your PHP syntax looks like?

Comment: It works in IE and firefox on my system: http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/8241/stackoverflow.png

Comment: Strange. It works in IE9 (thanks. I tried it and it really works) but not in Chrome. Hmmm

Comment: Did you try this in your `succes`? `alert(data.ok + ":" + data.answer);`
Chrome 14.0.835.109  works!

Comment: @Nausik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2823/discussion-between-321x-and-nausik)

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover all the bases: are you sure your jQuery is up-to-date and not altered in any way?